# One route with two controllers

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I want to use one **url** with difference query parameters that would be processed by different controllers:

> GET  /areas  controllers.Application.getXTree(from: String, to: String)
>
> GET  /areas  controllers.Application.getChildren(parentId:String)

Now I have an error for second route:

> For request 'GET /areas?parentId=f785d5cc-c8f7-4ddf-a611-757c8f91f536'
> [Missing parameter: from]

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible:

> Many routes can match the same request. If there is a conflict, the first route (in declaration order) is used. [Routing-priority](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting#Routing-priority)

Try this:

```
GET /areas/:from/:to controllers.Application.getXTree(from: String, to: String)

GET /areas/:parentId controllers.Application.getChildren(parentId:String)
```

You could use as well

```
GET   /areas/*params          controllers.Application.xTreeOrChildren(params)
```

and then parse `params` by `Application.xTreeOrChildren` but I prefer the first solution.

See [ScalaRouting](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting) for more information.

Comment: I don't want to change url's logic such way, it breaks REST url rules (**GET /areas/:id** - means get info about one area with id = :id). Yes, second solution is works. I tried [Srid router](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSirdRouter)  but I encountered with some other difficulties in this way, but it is possible.